# Driver for MS Access in java

Tags: java, database, ms-access

My requirement is to use MS Access database using java.

What would be the best solution? Should I download and use sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver or should I follow the usual way of connecting to Access database by configuring it in WIndows system?

The application will run on Windows system and I am using Ubuntu for development.

What will be the best approach?

Comment: I thought the JDBC-ODBC driver was not only included in the default libraries, but is required to connect to a ODBC source, such as MSAccess.  I believe you can create a DNS manually as part of the connection `String` to the JDBC Driver Manager, but since MSAccess stopped working for me on 64bit machines, I've bothered with it and used other DB solutions...so it's been awhile

Comment: @MadProgrammer:
The client uses MS Access so I cannot help it.Thanks for the reply..

Answer (score 1):

The `JdbcOdbcDriver` would work in JDK7 or below but it was [removed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) in JDK8 and if you're using Ubuntu for development that won't work anyway; the odbc->Jdbc bridge is dependent on Windows.

You can look at a cross-platform solution: [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html). It's at worth looking at with your circumstances.