# "undefined symbol: SQLAllocEnv" error in Java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

I am using java to build an application which requires to use MS Access.
I am geting the following error when I run the project:

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/i386/libJdbcOdbc.so: undefined symbol: SQLAllocEnv

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

As you mention in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21925296/2144390) you are trying to do development in Linux (Ubuntu) for a project that will ultimately be deployed on Windows. I suspect that you are trying to use the JDBC-ODBC Bridge in Linux without having the appropriate driver software installed.

I have seen many answers that talk about using `unixODBC` and `MDB Tools` to manipulate an Access database under Linux, but in my own experience that hasn't worked out very well. Instead I would offer the following advice:

- If you are developing a project for Windows then do your development under Windows. Then you can use the JDBC-ODBC Bridge and an actual Microsoft Access ODBC driver. However, bear in mind that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from JDK8 and is not supported, as mentioned in the previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21925410/2144390).
- If you *must* do your development under Linux then use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) (or perhaps just [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/), which UCanAccess uses as its lower-level interface to Access database files) and deploy the required components with your application.

Comment: Thanks Gord for the solution. I will implement it.